# What's the optimal number of neighbors for a full node?

Tags: iri-node, neighbors

When running a full node, what's the optimal number of neighbors? Does it depend on the server's specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official IOTA cli-app has a `health` command that checks the health of the node. One of the checks is whether the node has between 4-9 neighbors. From Slack and everything published, that is as close to an official number as is currently available.

https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app/blob/master/lib/commands/health.js#L27

Answer (score 2):

Early docs suggest 7-9 high quality neighbors. I’ve been running full nodes for a while and this number works reasonably well.

Comment: Hi ralf, you could improve your answer by providing a link to those "early docs"

Comment: Source: https://www.iotasupport.com/gui-addneighbors.shtml

Comment: Note that the link is not pointing to an official IOTA outlet.